# Tracking AJAX error on readystate 0, status 0 and statusText error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I read all these similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018247/jquery-ajax-error-readystate0-responsetext-status0-statustexterr), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555285/ajax-response-readystate-0-responsetext-status-0-statustext-error), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395354/jquery-ajax-readystate-0-responsetext-status-0-statustext-error), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818939/jquery-post-respond-with-readystate0-status0), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354121/occasional-ajax-response-error-readystate-0-status-0-statustext-error-usi) and [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339795/ajax-with-jquery-and-php-error-error-readystate-0-responsetext-status). But I need to debug more.

All of that questions say that problem is due to cross domain policy and `e.preventDefault()` solves problem. But I doubt that this can break some other things so I need to be sure.

In my site I have an operation which is fired 15k times a day. When user visits a webpage, my javascript file checks for an element. If element exists it makes an AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // I do something here

    if ($('#mydiv').length !== 0) {

       var startTime = new Date().getTime();        

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/mypage",
           success: function (data) {
               // I do something here
           },
           timeout: 20000,
           error: function(r, s, e) {
               var elapsedTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime );
               var string = "readyState: "+r.readyState+", status: "+r.status+", statusText: "+r.statusText+", responseText: "+r.responseText+", textStatus: "+s+", error: "+e +", elapsedTime: "+elapsedTime;
               // send this string to server for logging
              formData = {string:string};
              $.ajax({
                url : "/mylog",
                type: "POST",
                data : formData
              });
           }
       });
     }

    // I do something here
});
```

For the 15k requests, ~70 times user gets AJAX error. ~20 is due to timeout. ~50 is due to an unknown error. When I check clients' logs I see that AJAX request gives these values for unknown error: `readyState: 0, status: 0 and statusText: error`

Although e.preventDefault() is recommended for this issue. I need to know what user makes for this error. In my javascript file I don't make any cross domain request. But I can't know what user made for this error ? Is it possible to know more for this error ?

Note: I track the time between "AJAX call start" and "AJAX error". Average time is 1500-2000 ms.

Edit: If I use `preventDefault()`, where can I put it ? Because I don't register a click function etc.

Edit2: [This page](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.tr/2012/02/ajax-request-returns-status-0.html) says this:

> We found out that this could happen if the ajax request is getting
>   canceled before it completes. We could reproduce the problem if we
>   triggered the ajax request and then immediately click on a link to
>   navigate away from the page. jQuery throws the error event when the
>   user navigates away from the page either by refreshing, clicking a
>   link, or changing the URL in the browser.

But I couldn't reproduce the problem by clicking some link while AJAX is loading.

Comment: were you able to figure this one out? I've been experiencing nearly an identical situation in which seemingly random requests at about your rate or slightly higher fail with statusText=error and status=0. Thanks!

Comment: I can repeat this error pressing Esc key during ajax load. When I press Esc key, ajax stops and error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

I was facing the same issue. This issue occurs when there is redirect after the ajax call.

**Broken Code :**

```
$.ajax({
                url: '',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (json) {
                    // do stuff here
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // do stuff here
                }
            });

 window.location.href = "www.google.com";
```

In the above code, there is redirect after the ajax which gives error of ready state 0.

**Solution :**
    Write redirect after getting some response. I wrote within complete.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (json) {
                    // do stuff here
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // do stuff here
                },
                complete: function () {
                    window.location.href = "www.google.com";
                }
            });
```